# menu link title overriding form title in content part!

Tags: forms

I gave a menu link path to a form. Then when I click on that menu link, the form appears, but the form has the title, that of the "Menu link", which means that the menu link title overrides the form title.

Comment: I think its reverse the form title is set as menu link title

Comment: i have a different menu link title, through which i want access that form, which in turn has a different title.

Comment: but I dont think menu link title can override the form title